# google sheets match drop down indexes

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheets spreadsheet with 6 columns (A-F) each have a different drop down list that have been setup with it's own data validation rules. I want to achieve a scenario that if I select an option from a dropdown in column A, it selects the same index in column C for that row.

Is this possible?

Example

Column A Dropdown options: "item 1: apple", "item 2: banana", "item 3: car",

Column B Dropdown options: "item 1: dog", "item 2: egg", "item 3: farmer"

If i select item 1 in column A dropdown can it auto select item 1 from column b dropdown, etc. item 1 maps to item 1, item 2 maps to item 2 and so on

Comment: `it selects the same index in column C for that row.` I'm sorry but I'm finding this confusing. It's not clear what is meant by the words: `the same index`. Would you please clarify this. Since each column has its own dropdown validation rule, would you please edit your question to include some sample data and an example of the expected value for Column C.

Comment: Though I slightly understood your expected result. I am with @Tedinoz with this one.  There are vague things with your post. It would help if you provide a minimum reproducible sample.  For starters Dropdowns and OnEdit have some sort of limitation with them. Would you be open on removing dropdown on where to display data that was to be on C instead? Or the likes of this work around?

Comment: I've updated with an example, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sync Col C dropdown to Col A Dropdown.

This is possible with the use of Google Apps Script.

### Sample Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var changeCol = e.range.getColumn();
  if (changeCol == 1) { // Checking of Reference Cell for Change Triggers
    var cell = e.range;
    var rule = cell.getDataValidation();
    var criteria = rule.getCriteriaValues();
    var cellValue = e.value;
    var index = criteria[0].indexOf(cellValue);
    var changedRow = e.range.getRow();
    var adjustSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var adjustRange = adjustSS.getRange(changedRow, 3); // 3 refers to Column C on your question

    var adjustRule = adjustRange.getDataValidation();
    var adjustCriteria = adjustRule.getCriteriaValues();
    adjustRange.setValue(adjustCriteria[0][index]);
  }
}
```

What this code does is detect Changes on Col A Dropdown. Mimic the Index of the Change to Col C.

### Screen Recording of How it Works:

[image]

### References:

[Data Validation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation)

[On Edit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

Comment: If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)